# Unit Test - Flutter : MissingStubError: 'get' No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mockito

I was writing my unit test case to check the sample google book api call as below:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'fetch_book_test.mocks.dart';
@GenerateMocks([http.Client])
void main() {
  group("Fetch book api call test", () {
    test("should return list of books for http success call", () async {
      //ARRANGE
      final mockClient = MockClient();
      when(mockClient.get(Uri.parse(searchBookApiUrl))).thenAnswer(
          (realInvocation) async => http.Response(
              '{"items": ["title": "Beginning Flutter",]}', 200));
      //ACT & ASSERT
      expect(await fetchBooks("flutter", mockClient),isA<Book>());
    });
  });
}
```

I have added both the dependency in pubspec.yaml file as below:

> mockito: ^5.4.2
> build_runner: ^2.4.6

You can check the model class which I created is as below:

```
class Book {
  final String? id;
  final String? title;
  final String? author;
  final String? notes;
  final String? photoUrl;
  final String? categories;
  final String? publishedDate;
  final double? rating;
  final String? description;
  final int? pageCount;
  final Timestamp? startedReading;
  final Timestamp? finishedReading;
  final String? userId;

  Book({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.author,
    this.notes,
    this.photoUrl,
    this.categories,
    this.publishedDate,
    this.rating,
    this.description,
    this.pageCount,
    this.startedReading,
    this.finishedReading,
    this.userId,
  });

  factory Book.fromDocument(QueryDocumentSnapshot data) {

    return Book(
        id: data.id,
        title: data.get('title'),
        author: data.get('author'),
        notes: data.get('notes'),
        photoUrl: data.get('photo_url'),
        categories: data.get('categories'),
        publishedDate: data.get('published_date'),
        rating: parseDouble(data.get('rating')),
        description: data.get('description'),
        pageCount: data.get('page_count'),
        startedReading: data.get('started_reading_at'),
        finishedReading: data.get('finished_reading_at'),
        userId: data.get('user_id')
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'title': title,
      'user_id': userId,
      'author': author,
      'notes': notes,
      'photo_url': photoUrl,
      'published_date': publishedDate,
      'rating': rating,
      'description': description,
      'page_count': pageCount,
      'started_reading_at': startedReading,
      'finished_reading_at': finishedReading,
      'categories': categories,
    };
  }
}
```

I am using Google's Book Api: **https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flutter**

I am calling this api as inside below function:

```
  Future<List<Book>> fetchBooks(String searchQuery, http.Client client) async {
  List<Book> bookList = [];
  final response = await client.get(Uri.parse("$searchBookApiUrl$searchQuery"));

  if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final Iterable bookListIterable = body['items'];
    for (var book in bookListIterable) {
      final title = book['volumeInfo']['title'] ?? "N/A";
      final publishedDate = book['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'] ?? "N/A";
      final pageCount = book['volumeInfo']['pageCount'] ?? 0;
      final thumbNail = book['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'] ?? "N/A";
      final description = book['volumeInfo']['description'] ?? "N/A";
      final categories = book['volumeInfo']['categories'] == null
          ? "N/A"
          : book['volumeInfo']['categories'][0];
      final author = book['volumeInfo']['authors'] == null
          ? "N/A"
          : book['volumeInfo']['authors'][0];

      Book searchedBook = Book(
        title: title,
        author: author,
        photoUrl: thumbNail,
        description: description,
        publishedDate: publishedDate,
        pageCount: pageCount,
        categories: categories,
      );

      bookList.add(searchedBook);
      //print(book['volumeInfo']['title']);
    }
  } else {
    throw ('error ${response.reasonPhrase}');
  }
  return bookList;
}
```

But it give me below error:
Also generated the mockito class.

**But, Getting below error while executing the testcase:**

> > MissingStubError: 'get' No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
> > get(https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flutter, {headers:
> > null})
>
> Add a stub for this method using Mockito's 'when' API, or generate the
> MockClient mock with the @GenerateNiceMocks annotation

What might be the issue?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the error?